# Power Apps: Setting the default value of a dropdown to the second item

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I'm using a dropdown in my Power Apps app. The default value for the dropdown is defined this way:

`If(Form1.Mode = FormMode.New, "-", Parent.Default)`

The possible options are:

- `-`
- Person A
- Person B
- Person C

I would like to change the default value to the second option in the dropdown list. How would I go about doing that? I don't want to hardcode "Person A", because the list is dynamic and can change. I tried playing with `Choices` but couldn't get it to work.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to provide the Dropdown items from a datasource or a collection like this (I'll use a collection for the example but will work the same with a datasource) :

```
[App] OnStart : ClearCollect(_options; ["-", "Person A", "Person B", "Person C"])
```

Then, you set your Items property :

```
[Dropdown1] Items : _options
```

After that, you use a combinaison with "Last" and "FirstN" for the 2th item in default value:

```
[Dropdown1] Default : Last(FirstN(_options, 2)).Value
```

Have a good day